# Business Analytics and Story teller app

Tags: gratis, osx, data-visualization, data-analysis, business-intelligence

I use on my iPad an app called Roambi Analytics and Flow http://roambi.com/.

You can load a CSV file, choose templates or create your own and visualize the data. In the Flow you can also create stories with the visualizations and the results. In addition, the app calculation automatically, several KPIs and metrics from your file.

I am looking something similar for OS X or a cloud version.

To sum up:

- Business analytics
- Visualizations
- Story tellers
- OS X or Cloud
- Gratis/Free